# How to change a no to a yes in an external text file

Tags: python

I would like to change the no values on different lines to yes.
I am not sure how to do it without overwriting the whole file. This question is part of my Capstone project.

Question:
Add the following functionality when the user selects ‘vm’ to view all the
tasks assigned to them:
o Display all tasks in a manner that is easy to read. Make sure that
each task is displayed with a corresponding number which can be
used to identify the task.
o Allow the user to select either a specific task (by entering a number)
or input ‘-1’ to return to the main menu.
o If the user selects a specific task, they should be able to choose to
either mark the task as complete or edit the task. If the user
chooses to mark a task as complete, the ‘Yes’/’No’ value that
describes whether the task has been completed or not should be
changed to ‘Yes’. When the user chooses to edit a task, the
username of the person to whom the task is assigned or the due
date of the task can be edited. The task can only be edited if it has
not yet been completed.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

The code I have so far:

```
def view_mine():
    f = open("tasks.txt", "r").readlines()
    for index, value in enumerate(f, 1):
        v = value.split(", ")
        print(f"Task Number: {index}")
        print(f"Task : {v[1]} \nAssigned to : {v[0]} \nDate Assigned : {v[3]} \nDue Date : {v[4]} \nTask Complete? {v[5]} \nTask Description : {v[2]} \n")
    select_task = int(input("Please enter the Task Number of the Task you would like to edit:"))
    if select_task in range(1, select_task + 1):
        choice = input('''Please enter an edit option:
                c - Complete
                e - Edit
                0 - Exit
                :''').lower()
        if choice == "0":
            return
        elif choice == "c":
            f = open("tasks.txt", "r").readlines()
            for line in f:
                if "No" in line:
                    oriline = line
                    newline = line.replace("No","Yes")
                elif "Yes" in line:
                    print("This task is completed and cannot be edited.")
            f = open("tasks.txt", "r").read()
            filedata = f.replace(oriline, newline)
            f = open("tasks.txt", "w")
            f.write(filedata)
            print("The Task has been marked to completed.")
```

Comment: Please, include the issue you face with your code. And provide [mre]. It is also useful to go over the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring user input, here's how you could implement the core functionality:

```
def change_no_to_yes(filename: str):
    with open(filename, 'r+') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            if 'No' in line:
                lines[i] = line.replace('No', 'Yes')
            elif 'Yes' in line:
                # somewhat pointless message as there's no context
                print('This task is completed and cannot be edited.')
        file.seek(0)
        file.writelines(lines)
```

Open the file and read all lines. Enumerate the lines. For any line containing 'No', replace with 'Yes' updating the list of lines. For any line containing 'Yes' print a message.

Seek to the start of the file. Rewrite all lines.

If no changes have been made (i.e., 'No' was never replaced with 'Yes') you could use a boolean flag to indicate such a change and therefore avoid rewriting the file for optimum performance.

Note: If you were replacing 'Yes' with 'No' you would need to call file.truncate() before closing (exiting the context manager) because the file may have become smaller. In this scenario the file can only ever get larger so file.truncate() is irrelevant